# Animate ::before and ::after

Tags: html, css

I searched `::before` and `::after` up, and I understand that HTML is not rendered inside of the pseudo-elements. I have a Unicode character(Ξ) before and after a certain text element, and I would like to animate them, and only those characters. Is there a trick to inserting HTML elements into `::before` and `::after` elements or animating only those elements? Or should I just separately insert them into the code and animate them separately?

My current code:

```css
.side div h2::before {
  content: "Ξ";
  animation: spin 3s infinite;
}

.side h2::after {
  content: "Ξ";
  animation: spin 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="side">
  <div style="height:100%;">
    <h2>Navigation</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can animate them as you would normal elements

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I tried to, but rotation(what I intend to do) does not seem to work.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Reset display to inline-block for the pseudo.transform Will then work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` for `transform: rotate` to work on `::before` and `::after`:

```css
div::before,
div::after {
  content: "Ξ";
  display: inline-block;
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>TEST</div>
```

Or, `display: block` if you want some madness:

```css
div::before,
div::after {
  content: "Ξ";
  display: block;
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>TEST</div>
```